# How to print out a particular value from a dictionary

Tags: python, json

I am trying to access last_login which is the first value in my json string, I want to then print this out to the user.

dictionary

> user = {"last_login":null, "is_active":false}

dictionary output

> {"last_login":null, "is_active":false}

dictionary output

> {"last_login":null}

Comment: This is an invalid dictionary, not a tuple.

Comment: @ForceBru well, looks more like poorly formatted json to me... (given null and false)

Comment: `null`?? In Python this should be `None`...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yes, and "false" would be `False` - hence why I said JSON :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

> print user["last_login"];